# Undefined reference to 'this' in Typescript class

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm having an issue with Typescript in which the `this` key word is showing up as undefined when debugging and, therefore, not calling some of my private class methods which are called from a callback method. My text editor seems to think that my reference is fine and is giving me intellensense, so I would assume the code is ok. below is a shortened example. The `cacheUser` and `_processSuccessfulRegistration` are not getting hit when the `_handleCreationResponse` callback method is called.

```
export class User extends Observable {
    public email: string;
    public password: string;
    public username: string

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.email = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.username = '';
    }

    public register() {
        let user = {
            // build out object
        }
        userService.createAccount(user)
            .catch(/* handle error */)
            .then(this._handleCreationResponse)
    }

    private _handleCreationResponse(response) {
        let status = response.status;
        let userData = response.result;

        switch (status) {
            case ApiStatus.Success:
                this._cacheUser(userData);
                this._processSuccessfulRegistration(userData);
                break;
            case ApiStatus.SomeError:
                // handle errors
                break;
            default:
                // do something else 
                break;
        }
    }

    private _cacheUser(user) {
        // handle user caching
    }

    private _processSuccessfulRegistration() {
        // call some other services and 
        // navigate to a new view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass functions as callbacks the functions are not bound to a specific `this`, so when they get executed `this` will refer to something else.

To avoid that you can either [bind the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
userService.createAccount(user)
            .catch(/* handle error */)
            .then(this._handleCreationResponse.bind(this)
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which do save the right context for this:

```
userService.createAccount(user)
            .catch(/* handle error */)
            .then(response => this._handleCreationResponse(response))
```

---

#### Edit

There's another option which is to create this method as an arrow function to begin with:

```
private _handleCreationResponse = (response) => {
    let status = response.status;
    let userData = response.result;

    switch (status) {
        case ApiStatus.Success:
            this._cacheUser(userData);
            this._processSuccessfulRegistration(userData);
            break;
        case ApiStatus.SomeError:
            // handle errors
            break;
        default:
            // do something else 
            break;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it as you did before and the context of `this` will be preserved.
If you use this option be aware that it's a bit different than what you had before as `_handleCreationResponse` won't be a method anymore but a function property of the instance (that is, it won't be part of the prototype).

Here's a short example to show the difference:

```
class MyClass {
    method1() {
        console.log("method 1");
    }

    method2 = () => {
        console.log("method 2");
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.method2 = function () {
            console.log("method 2");
        };
    }
    MyClass.prototype.method1 = function () {
        console.log("method 1");
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

You cannot override methods which are arrow functions in extending classes, but as your method is private it shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: Fantastic answer! One question wouldn't I need to do `.then((response)=>{this._handleUserCreateResponse(response)})` in order to get the arrow function method to pass the response into the private method? That seemed to be the only way to get that to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My bad, but I edited it and it's fixed now.